# Can't remote access to mysql in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have two virtual machine in VirtualBox with clean installation Ubuntu server.

I need to mysql connect from one to another VM. I allow access from my second VM with ip 192.168.1.80. In first VM in mysql config I write down:

```
bind-address = 192.168.1.80
```

I connect from second VM via user = root, therefore I changed host to % in user table in first VM.
Then I allowed connect in ufw by different ways:

[image: ufw status]

First VM successfully pings from second.
When I try to connect:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.118 -u root -p
```

I see:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.118' (111)
```

I open ports, allow connect in mysql config. What else should I do?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a question for server fault?

Comment: You are trying to connect to MySQL on 192.168.1.118, while you have configured MySQL to only listen on 192.168.1.80... If .118 is hosting MySQL, then you should configure `bind-address=192.168.1.118`, or otherwise you need to connect to 192.168.1.80, not to .118... The value of `bind-address` needs to be an IP address valid for that server, it is not about which clients can connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind Address and Mysql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552680/bind-address-and-mysql-server)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel If I set ip .118 or 0.0.0.0 or I comment out this line nothing changes. That link doesn't help.

Comment: You need to restart MySQL for the changes to take effect. In any case, if that doesn't work for you, re-ask your question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ (or maybe https://serverfault.com/). It is off-topic here (it is not a programming question).

Comment: Of course I restart mysql. Ok, I reask this question on serverfault, thanks.