# How to run two instances of Kafka rest

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I am trying to run a second instance for Kafka Rest. Here's the properties file for the first one:

```
id=kafka-rest-test-server-1
schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081,http://localhost:9081
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183
bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094
```

According to [Confluent's docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/deployment.html#deployment):

> The only requirement for multiple instances is that you set a unique
>   id for each instance.

However, when I run the second instance with other `id`, an exception is thrown mentioning that the address is already in use:

```
WARN FAILED io.confluent.rest.Application$1@41294f8: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle:212)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID doesn't control the port. "Multiple instances" in the documentation means independent machines

Just like the Schema Registry, configure the `listeners`

> `listeners`
>   Comma-separated list of listeners that listen for API requests over either HTTP or HTTPS
>
> Default: “http://0.0.0.0:8082“

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/config.html#kafkarest-config

`port` property is deprecated, but if you're running an old version, wouldn't hurt to set it as well

For example, first instance, leave the defaults

Second instance, use any available port

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:18082
```

It is generally recommended that you use more than one machine for high availability and distributed processing. Running 3 Zookeepers, 3 Brokers, 2 Registries, and 2 Proxies, you're basically begging to run out of RAM

Comment: Just to make it clear, say that I want to run two kafka connect instances on http://0.0.0.0:8082 and http://1.1.1.1:8082, should I place both listenes on both files e.g. `listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8082,http://1.1.1.1:8082` or should I place only one listener per instance?

Comment: Assuming you mean REST Proxies. It's a bind address. You can list as many as you want, but anything other than 0.0.0.0 will take precedence and limit connectivity. See general description at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552680/bind-address-and-mysql-server    My point was to change the port number